# Quais as limitações da licença gratuita do Visual Studio Online?

Tags: visual-studio, licença

No site do Visual Studio Online existe uma opção de conta gratuita. Lá diz que essa conta oferece os seguintes benefícios:

- 5 licenças de usuário básico GRÁTIS
- Participantes ilimitados
- Assinantes qualificados do MSDN ilimitados
- Repositórios de códigos privados e projetos de equipe ilimitados
- Acompanhamento de itens de trabalho GRÁTIS para todos os usuários
- 60 minutos/mês de compilação GRÁTIS
- 20 mil minutos de usuário virtual/mês de teste de carga GRÁTIS
- Análise e monitoramento de aplicativos de VISUALIZAÇÃO

Acontece que isso é vantagem demais. Repositórios privados no GitHub são pagos e essa conta oferece repositórios privados ilimitados de graça. Como parece ter muita vantagem aí fiquei me perguntando sobre as limitações dessa conta.

Quais limitações essa licença oferece? Projetos comerciais podem ser hospedados lá ou só projetos open source ou gratuitos? É como o Visual Studio Community que pode ser usado sem limitações para desenvolvedores que trabalham fora de empresas?

Comment: A lista do que cita como vantagens, me parece limitações da licença, em primeira leitura cheguei a pensar que era uma propaganda do produto. Acredito que se a pergunta for reformulada é dividida em três como é feita no final ficaria melhor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É exatamente isto que você descreveu. A Microsoft não pode dar vantagens demais para seus usuários? :)

Qualquer projeto pode ser hospedado lá. Qualquer um pode usar em qualquer circunstância.

Na verdade, não é tão vantajoso assim para alguns tipos de usuários. Se mais do que 5 pessoas podem acessar o projeto você tem que partir para o pago. Mas se sua equipe é pequena é grátis mesmo. Não tem pegadinha. E pode ainda ter usuários extras desde que eles possuam uma conta paga ativa na MSDN (que vem junto com algumas edições do Visual Studio).

Note que é possível acessar *work items* e algumas outras coisas por usuários fora do projeto sem restrição. Ou seja, todos seus usuários podem ver e incluir *tickets*, acompanhar a evolução do projeto. Eles só não podem acessar o projeto como um todo e executar qualquer coisa, e provavelmente não é o que você quer mesmo.

Até onde eu sei ainda não está disponível em português (isto pode estar defasado).

Para equipes assim eu duvido que as outras limitações sejam muito problemáticas, e na verdade até são em cima de coisas que o Github, por exemplo, não oferece (agora não mão da Microsoft oferece algo bem semelhante).

Claro que a Microsoft não está sendo boazinha. Ela está dando muita coisa de graça para quem não pode pagar. Mas a concorrência também está dando. Pode não ser a mesma coisa, mas dão outras. Ela precisa mostrar que é barato usar suas tecnologias. E ela ainda ganha bastante com quem precisa mais e pode pagar por isto. Estes usam produtos Microsoft porque precisam, coisas grátis não vão influenciá-los.

A Microsoft também espera que um dia você que usa grátis cresça e seja um usuário pagante.

Agora ele se chama Azure DevOps.

E mais recentemente deve usar o [Github Codespaces](https://github.com/features/codespaces).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado @bigown, eu já perguntei do VS Community e agora sobre o VSO porque realmente estou estranhando isso tudo ainda. Sempre trabalhei sozinho e antigamente o jeito era usar o VS Express mesmo porque o preço dos VS completos era meio complicado pra quem trabalha sozinho. Ainda bem que agora a MS está facilitando um pouco mais as coisas.

Comment: A MS está precisando conquistar desenvolvedores porque sem eles fazendo aplicações para suas plataformas ela não pode vender as plataformas. E ela sabe que quem é pequeno, não faz nada muito visível se realmente quer usar os softwares dela, vai usar pagando ou não. Não estou dizendo aqui publicamente que é isto que você deva fazer mas sabemos que muita gente faz.

Comment: Alguem sabe se as Team Room são gratuitas? pelo que vi tem que pagar, ou são gratuitas também?

Comment: http://www.visualstudio.com/pricing/visual-studio-online-pricing-vs os pacotes pagos possuem mais recursos mas até onde eu percebo está incluso nas contas gratuitas para até 5 usuários.